# Rotate sqlite records in one columns

Tags: sqlite

Is there any way to rotate the records in an sqlite database column from top to bottom or from bottom to top? Could this be done with a query?

[image]

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes We have  options to do same task:

Record and reverse them into array

```
ArrayList<Type> tempList = new ArrayList<Type>();
Collections.reverse(tempList);
```